# get images URL in a twig template

Tags: theming, 8, nodes, entities

I have two content types, the first is **Homepage** and the second is **SLider**.
The **Slider** content type has multiple fields like title, ink, and image.
In the **homepage** content type, I have an entity reference field referring to the **slider** content type with multiple selections. I've created a template in my custom theme as `node--home-page.html` and want to get the sliders fields values, All is okay with me except the image. I cannot get the image URL. 
My code:-

```
{% for slide in node.field_hoeme_slideshows %}
        {{ kint(slide.entity.field_home_slide_cta.uri) }} {# This is working #}
        {{ kint(slide.entity.title.value) }} {# This is working #}
        {{ kint(slide.entity.field_home_slide_snippet.value) }} {# This is working #}
        {{ kint(slide.entity.field_home_slide_image) }} {# ****** This is not working *****#}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Do you really need the raw url value? `{{ slide.entity.field_home_slide_image }}` should print the entire `<img>` tag, including responsive styles, if configured.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried it and got this error `Exception: Object of type Drupal\file\Plugin\Field\FieldType\FileFieldItemList cannot be printed. in Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter() (line 465 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension.php).`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative configuration using Field Collections. Instead of using two content types and a field reference...

```
{% for item in content.field_slide %}
<a href="{{ item.getFieldCollectionItem().field_link.0.url }}">
    <figure class="my-class {% if loop.first %}{{ 'first-class' }}{% endif %}  {% if loop.last %}{{ 'last-class' }}{% endif %}">

        <div class="my-image-wrapper">

            <img src="{{ file_url(item.getFieldCollectionItem().field_slide_image.0.entity.uri.0.value) }}" alt="{{ item.getFieldCollectionItem().field_slide_image.0.alt }}" title="{{ item.getFieldCollectionItem().field_slide_image.0.title }}" />

        </div>

        <h2>{{ item.getFieldCollectionItem().field_h2.0.value }}</h2>
        <figcaption>{{ item.getFieldCollectionItem().field_p.0.value }}</figcaption>

    </figure>
</a>
{% endfor %}
```

This is off the top of my head so double check the code.

Then you just create a field collection field on the home page content type called slide. Go to field collections, select "slide" and add the fields: link, slide_image, h2, and p.

Comment: Field Collection module not stable for Drupal 8. So I'm asking if it's working good with you and What about Paragraph module

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ file_url(content.field_image['#items'].entity.uri.value }}

{{ file_url(content.field_image['#items'].entity.uri.value | image_style('1440px')) }}
```

Im not sure of your current setup.... but you might need to try something like "item in node.field_home_slideshows['#items']"

(note: you spelled home, hoeme)

inside do...

```
file_url(item.entity.uri.value)
```

This is twig valid:

```
{% for item in content.field_image['#items'] %}
 {{ file_url(item.entity.uri.value }},
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: To add the image_style filter you will need to install the module "twig tweak".... and ensure that you select the same image style in the display settings of the field on the content type

Comment: Sorry, I am printing out "content.field...." but it may be "slide.field...", or other, depending on where you are accessing your field. Using {{ dump(_context | keys) }} will show you everything available in your current template

Comment: If you're going to down vote please tell us why. As far as I know looks like he needs an image URL. What you need to do is {{ dump() }} and search for the appropriate fields uri key. Then you convert that uri key value to a usable URL using file_url()